# What integer data type has a scope greater than integer in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I initialized a model with field `:price`. The values in this field have a minimum value of one million and I don't know what kind of data to use in the migration file.

```
class CreateTours < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :tours do |t|
      t.references :detail, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :price
      t.datetime :start_date
      t.integer :tour_quantity

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these command at your ruby command line and observe the output. It can handle not just million but decillion.

```
puts 1_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000.instance_of? Fixnum
puts 1_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000.instance_of? Bignum
puts 1_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000.instance_of? Integer
```

As of Ruby 2.5.0 it will return
Deprecate,
Deprecate,
True

Yes, **Bignum** and **Fixnum** are now combined into just one type **Integer**

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.